# "The model backing the 'DataContext' context has changed" but I am on the same migration

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, console-application, entity-framework-migrations

I have a C# solution. Recently, we moved the solution into a **new** repository.

In the OLD solution, I have a soon-to-be **deprecated** console app that accesses my Azure-hosted DB to do some work. We had some new DB migrations in the new repository and had some work that required the console app, so I moved the app project over into a throwaway branch in the new repo just so I could build it with the latest migrations.

It compiles fine. However, when I try to run it, I ALWAYS get the `The model backing the 'DataContext' context has changed` error.

What's weird about this is that **my code and my DB are on the same migration.** I can even run the `update-database` command on that DB and it tells me that I have "no pending migrations". I did compares on the stored procedures in my visual studio and the DB and they are all equal. Same results when trying `Add-Migration "SyncTest"`, it creates a migration with no changes.

I cannot delete the `__MigrationHistory` table because I need to run this console app on production servers and cannot afford to lose that data/have any downtime.

So if I am on the same migration step between my console app and my DB, then *why* is it still throwing this error? I dunno where else to check!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why it is happening in your particular case, but I did stumble across a way to turn off the error, put this line in your DbContext instance ctor:

```
Database.SetInitializer<YourDbContextClass>(null);
```

Comment: Cool, this is a nice workaround and lets me run the script, thanks. I still would like to know why it thinks there is a migrations difference though!